# Ajax post function not show data in list

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to create a Popup window in ASP.Net Core application, to create a new customer or edit an existing customer, by using Ajax. But when I execute the Post request the data is not being showed in the customers list. I need to refresh the page in order to show this data, and I don't know what's the problem.

This is my Ajax method:

```js
PostCustomer = form => {
 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                if (res.isValid) {
                    $('#view-all-customer').html(res.html)
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                    $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                    $('#form-model').modal('hide');
                }
                else
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
        return false;
    
    }
```

this is my function in controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CreateOrUpdate(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Insert
            if (customer.CustomerId == 0)
            {
                 _customerRepository.Create(customer);

            }
            //Update
            else
            {
               
                    _customerRepository.Update(customer);
             
            }
            return Json(new { isValid = true, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_ViewAllCustomer" , List()) });
        }


        return Json(new { isValid = false, html = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "CreateOrUpdate", customer) });
    }
```

Comment: what is `view-all-customer` a `class` or `id` ?

Comment: @Swati Class , i am edit my question

Comment: Then there should be `.` instead of `#`

Comment: @Swati I already added it # but the same problem

Comment: Need to be a lot more specific about what is or isn't happening and include more debugging details

Comment: You should start with verifying that all your server-side code works with e.g. Postman. If server-side runs as depicted, it is a js-problem. Else, add your test-payloads in question.

Comment: I'm confused about this line: `$('#form-model').modal('hide');` because I thought you want to **show** your Popup window, not to **hide** it. Have you tried changing it to `$('#form-model').modal('show');` or `$('#form-model').modal('toggle');`?

Comment: @Sagnalrac No,There is already another JQuery method working on displaying popup window, I want when it adding or modifying data successfully, the popup window will be closed and then this data will appear on the menu.